# pecl install zmq not found

Tags: php, zeromq, pear, pecl

Have XAMPP on Windows, php 5.5.19, PEAR 1.10.0dev2

I tried to install **zmq**, buto not found the package in `pecl`:

`pecl install zmq` or `pecl install zmq-beta` **:**

```
 No releases available for package pecl.php.net/zmq 

 No releases available for package pecl.php.net/zmq-beta
```

https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are DLLs available for download from zmq's package page on pecl - https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq so you might not need to install via pecl afterall...

Comment: I tried DLLs, but have a series of problems when loading module, for this reason now trying install it via `pecl `. is not possible? you are tried?

Comment: after download DLLs zip file, is there 4 files named `php_zmq.pdb` , `php_zmq.dll` , `libzmq.pdb` , `libzmq.dll` i copied all these file in `ext` folder and `php` folder, now it work correctly. Before only put dll files in `ext` and `php` folders, it was the reason that i could not install the `zmq` extension from DLLs file. Now it works very well. Thanks.